# Give space as an input in String Concatenate functoid

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-mapper

I am trying to use **String Concatenate** Functoid to concatenate **FirstName and LastName to FullName**. I want a space in between FirstName and LastName. I want to add a space as input but it is not accepting.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When concatenating two (or more) strings, you can add a new constant item to the list of functoid inputs and assign a 'space' as constant value:

[image]